# What is the relationship between combinatorics and graph theory?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I’m a computer science student who’s taken two discrete math courses where I learned a lot about graph theory and a little bit about combinatorics. I see often that the two fields blend, and I was just wondering why. I see the term “combinatorial graph theory” often as well, and just want to understand better the intertwined relationship between the two.

I bought a graph theory book after my course because I thought the subject was very interesting, and one of the practice problems in the book was what seemed to be a combinatorics question, asking how many chess matches would be played if 5 people played each other only once. I understood that the answer could be found in a complete graph, but is it usually the case where combinatorics questions can be answered with a graph?

Comment: It is like you can use algebra to solve calculus problems. Similarly, you can use combinatorics to find various methods of counting problems that arise from graph theory. You can use graph theory to help understand topology and group theory. They are intertwined because they can all be used to investigate the same set of underlying problems.

Comment: Graph theory might be considered a subfield of combinatorics, depending on who you ask.  Both are considered "discrete math".

Comment: Lots of graph theory problems boil down to (or are an extension of) counting problems, which can then be solved with what we consider combinatorics!